# Proliant DL180G6, RAID controller: centos installation shows phisycal disks, not logical drive

Tags: centos7, raid-controller, hp-server-automation

I am installing centos 7 on Proliant DL180g6, with the logical drive.

I have 3 disks, with one RAID 1 arrays.
I see the logical drive on the controller but I can't see that on installation centos.

my controller is b110i. 
How can I solve this and properly use the RAID controller?

Comment: Did you install the proper drivers for RAID controller?

Comment: thanks. but how to install the driver without an operating system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the proper drivers loaded during installation process you can follow the procedure described on [this HP support page](https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c03249896&docLocale=en_US):

> Go to HP website.
>
> Click here to access the HPE website .
>
> Click Support & Drivers.
>
> Click Drivers and Software.
>
> Enter the controller model "B110i SATA RAID Controller" and click
>   Search.
>
> Select the Red Hat Operating System version in question (for example,
>   Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 Server (x86-64)).
>
> Click Software - Driver Update.
>
> Download the recommended Driver Diskette for HP Smart Array B110i SATA
>   RAID Controller for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 (AMD64/EM64T), the name
>   of the file should be hpahcisr-xx.xx.xx.rhel5.x86_64.dd.gz .
>
> Once the driver diskette file is downloaded using a Linux machine
>   (Desktop, Laptop, Server) extract the file using the command gzip -d
>   hpahcisr-xx.xx.xx.rhel5.x86_64.dd.gz or gunzip
>   hpahcisr-xx.xx.xx.rhel5.x86_64.dd.gz.
>
> Now proceed to create a USB Flash Driver to make it work as a
>   diskette, running the following command dd if=
>   hpahcisr-xx.xx.xx.rhel5.x86_64.dd of=/dev/device_name, see the
>   following example:
>
> In this case the USB Key was recognized with device name sdb;
>   therefore, the complete command is:
>
> `# dd if= hpahcisr-xx.xx.xx.rhel5.x86_64.dd of=/dev/sdb`
>
> Now, proceed to boot the server to install with the Operating System
>   in question. Below an example of the installation of Red Hat
>   Enterprise Linux 5 Server (x86-64).
>
> This is the RHEL 5 Installer first screen:
>
> Press F2-Options to check on which options are available. The
>   installer will show the following options to choose in which user can
>   find linux dd in order to load a driver disk, see the sample below:
>
> Once in there, plug the USB Flash Driver in which the driver disk has
>   been created so it can be recognized by the Installer. Then, as the
>   options states type linux dd and hit the Enter key. User should be
>   prompted with the following screen:
>
> Hit Yes option and then continue with the next screen. In this one
>   user will be prompted with the source of the driver disk. See below
>   sample:
>
> If users are prompted with two options sda should be the once since
>   scd0 is for the optical drive. In order to confirm, open tty4 pressing
>   both ctrl + alt keys at the same time plus F4 Key. See the sample
>   below in which list USB SanDisk (USB in used for this tutorial)
>   recognized as sda.
>
> Once this has been checked, return to Graphic Mode pressing both ctrl
>   + alt keys at the same time plus F1 Key in order to continue with the installation and press OK to proceed to use the USB driver disk. User
>   should see the progress of loading the driver module hpahcisr. See
>   sample below:
>
> Once the driver module loading process finish user should be prompted
>   for more driver disk to load. User must hit NO and continue with the
>   installation, see sample below:
>
> After this option is prompted user must continue with the normal
>   installation. The process will finish loading all necessary files to
>   continue. Once this is done on the Graphic Mode user will see that all
>   our Hard Disk Drives or single Hard Driver is recognized as HP LOGICAL
>   VOLUME and not separate Drives.

Comment: May I have some comment about the reason of downvote?

Comment: thanks a lot. I didn't downvote and I can't vote to this reply because I have less than 15 reputations.

Answer (score 2):

The B110i really is a fake raid controller - it requires a binary, opaque driver to be loaded into the OS kernel.

It will not buy you basically anything over software RAID, with the significant downside of using a proprietary driver and metadata.

So, I strongly suggest you to set the disk controller in AHCI/IDE mode and use Linux MDRAID instead of the proprietary one.